OpenXMLPowerTools.NetStandard version 4.6.0 Replace function maps "a" character to "alpha" character
I am using OpenXMLPowerTools.NetStandard version 4.6.0 and it converts "a" character into "alpha" character in OpenXmlRegex.Replace function. This was not seen in the OpenXMLPowerTools version 4.5.3.1 and previous ones but seen in 4.5.3.2 and latest maintained version OpenXMLPowerTools.NetStandard version. Is there a way of handling this issue? An observation, when I upload the original document to Google Docs and download it without changing anything, this issue does not occur.
